SFMC Passing Incorrect UTMs into URL
We are having an issue where we specifically set our UTM values for our URLs and use this as the URL in our buttons in Content Builder.
Example being: mysite.com/client-testimonials/?utm_campaign=EML_CA_Cnv_Factoring_NE_DOT_2&utm_term=hear_from_our_clients&utm_content=new_authority
However when the URL is passing over for us to see which link prompted a form submission the link is passing over as: mysite.com/client-testimonials/?utm_campaign={{Set Per Channel}}&utm_term=Join Our Clients&utm_content=88674&j=448352&sfmc_sub=158069253&l=2391_HTML&u=9205241&mid=534001763&jb=329&utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium={{Set Per Channel}}&utm_id=cfaef288-7e97-4b8f-8&sfmc_activityid={{Activity ID}}
Note: We use a third-party form submission tracking website, but this website just pulls the URL values and passes it over into their system, so their system would not have any impact on the URL being adjusted/reformatted.
In our SFMC setup under data management -> parameter management we have our Google Analytics Tracking set to be the following formula: https://yourlink.com?sfmc_journey_id={{Journey ID}}&sfmc_journey_name={{Journey Name}}&sfmc_activity_id={{Activity ID}}&sfmc_activity_name={{Activity Name}}&sfmc_channel={{Set Per Channel}}&sfmc_asset_id={{Asset ID}}
But, this is not matching exactly to show that this would be the root of the cause. Has anyone else had this issue or have any ideas what might be causing the UTMs to be repopulated and/or passed over incorrectly? If you have any idea how we could prevent this from happening, please let us know!
Another note: When I submit test submissions from our website this problem doesn't occur, it appears to only be happening when the email is sent out of journey builder and clicked by a prospect.
